# What does the "--" mean in "/bin/login -p --"?

Tags: login

When I login to Ubuntu via the text console, I can see that a `/bin/login` process is the parent process of my shell.  `login` is run as follows: `/bin/login -p --`.  This can be seen below:

```
$ ps -f -C login
UID          PID    PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         780       1  0 Apr27 tty2     00:00:00 /bin/login -p --
```

My question is, what is the significance of the final `--` argument?  This argument is not documented in the `login` manpage.

Comment: This was answered over at "Unix and Linux :  [https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other answers have described what the `--` means (end of option processing). Here I will try to answer how and why it arises in the context of the TTY-based `/bin/login` process.

Specifically, if you take a look at the `[Service]` section of `/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service` you should see the following `ExecStart` line:

```
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -o '-p -- \\u' --noclear %I $TERM
```

The reason for adding the `--` is documented in `man agetty`:

> ```
> SECURITY NOTICE
>        If  you  use  the --login-program and --login-options options, be aware
>        that a malicious user may try to enter lognames with embedded  options,
>        which then get passed to the used login program.  Agetty does check for
>        a leading "-" and makes sure the logname gets passed as  one  parameter
>        (so embedded spaces will not create yet another parameter), but depend‐
>        ing on how the login binary parses the command line that might  not  be
>        sufficient.   Check  that  the used login program cannot be abused this
>        way.
>
>        Some  programs use "--" to indicate that the rest  of  the  commandline
>        should not be interpreted as options.  Use this feature if available by
>        passing "--" before the username gets passed by \u.
> ```

Comment: So `getty` (or `agetty`?) runs the following: `/bin/login -p -- $USER`?  And then `/bin/login` removes/hides the `$USER`, with the result that `$USER` does not appear in the output of  `ps -f -C login`?

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot mark this as a duplicate of a non AksUbuntu stack exchange site...  ***I have shamelessly copied this answer over.***

In `man bash` we can read in *Shell Builtin Commands* section:

> Unless otherwise noted, each builtin command documented in this section as accepting options preceded by `-` accepts `--` **to signify the end of the options**.
>
> The `:`, `true`, `false`, and `test` builtins do not accept options and do not treat `--` specially.  The `exit`, `logout`, `break`, `continue`, `let`, and `shift` builtins accept and process arguments beginning with `-` without requiring `--`. Other builtins that accept arguments but are not specified as accepting options interpret arguments beginning with `-` as invalid options and require `--` to prevent this interpretation.
>
> Note that `echo` does not interpret `--` to mean the end of options.

Also

More precisely, a double dash (`--`) is used in most bash built-in commands and many other commands to signify the end of command options, after which only positional parameters are accepted.

Example use: lets say you want to grep a file for the string `-v` - normally `-v` will be considered the option to reverse the matching meaning (only show lines that do not match), but with `--` you can grep for string `-v` like this:

```
grep -- -v file
```